# How to write a statement level trigger in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

```
CREATE TABLE faculty
(f_id NUMBER(6),
f_last VARCHAR2(15),
f_first VARCHAR2(15),
f_mi CHAR(1),
loc_id NUMBER(5) not null,
f_phone VARCHAR2(10),
f_rank VARCHAR2(9),
f_salary number(9,2), 
f_super NUMBER(6), --supervisor/manager of the faculty member
f_pin NUMBER(4),
f_image BLOB, 
CONSTRAINT faculty_f_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(f_id),
CONSTRAINT faculty_loc_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (loc_id) REFERENCES location(loc_id));

--- inserting records into FACULTY
INSERT INTO faculty VALUES
(1, 'Marx', 'Teresa', 'J', 9, '4075921695', 'Associate', 75000.00, 4, 6338, EMPTY_BLOB());

INSERT INTO faculty VALUES
(2, 'Zhulin', 'Mark', 'M', 10, '4073875682', 'Full', 98000.00, NULL, 1121, EMPTY_BLOB());

INSERT INTO faculty VALUES
(3, 'Langley', 'Colin', 'A', 12, '4075928719', 'Assistant', 60000.00, 4, 9871, EMPTY_BLOB());

INSERT INTO faculty VALUES
(4, 'Brown', 'Jonnel', 'D', 11, '4078101155', 'Full', 102000.00, NULL, 8297, EMPTY_BLOB());

INSERT INTO faculty VALUES
(5, 'Sealy', 'James', 'L', 13, '4079817153', 'Associate', 80000.00, 1, 6089, EMPTY_BLOB());
```

**I wrote this ROW Level trigger(was below) already, but don't know how to get a statement level trigger which can do the same thing like this.** And because cannot use :NEW / :OLD in statement level, then confused...

```
--Row Level
create or replace TRIGGER TRG_F_SALARY_CHECK
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF F_SUPER ON FACULTY
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    IF :NEW.F_SUPER > :OLD.F_SUPER THEN
        :NEW.F_SALARY := :OLD.F_SALARY + 2000*(:NEW.F_SUPER - 5);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The salary has been updated');
    END IF;
    IF :NEW.F_SUPER < :OLD.F_SUPER THEN
        IF :OLD.F_SUPER >=5 THEN
            IF :NEW.F_SUPER < 5 THEN
                :NEW.F_SALARY := :OLD.F_SALARY - 2000*(:OLD.F_SUPER - 5);
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The salary has been updated');
            ELSE
              :NEW.F_SALARY := :OLD.F_SALARY - 2000*(:OLD.F_SUPER - :NEW.F_SUPER);
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The salary has been updated');
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;

create or replace TRIGGER TRG_F_SALARY_CHECK_STATEMENT
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF F_SUPER, F_SALARY ON FACULTY
DECLARE
  --  OLD_F_SUPER NUMBER(10);
    OLD_F_SALARY NUMBER(9);
BEGIN
--        SELECT F_SUPER INTO OLD_F_SUPER FROM FACULTY;
--       SELECT SUM(F_SALARY) INTO OLD_F_SALARY FROM FACULTY
--       WHERE F_ID;
   UPDATE FACULTY
   /* SET F_SALARY = F_SALARY + 2000*(F_SUPER -5)
        WHERE F_SUPER > 5;*/
        SET F_SALARY = OLD_F_SALARY + 2000*(F_SUPER - 5)
            WHERE F_SUPER > 5;
END;
```

btw, table `FACULTY` has including in `F_ID`, `F_SALARY`, `F_SUPER`, etc.. I am going to get ** one-row trigger**(already done) and **one statement trigger** for updating the salary of faculty with changing of `F_SUPER` number.
For every single `F_SUPER` change(increase or decrease) after 5, `F_SALARY` will change(increase or decrease) for $2000.

The test code is below:

```
/*F_ID = 5, F_SUPER = 7, F_SALARY = 84000*/
UPDATE FACULTY
SET F_SUPER = 7
WHERE F_ID = 5;
/*F_ID =5, F_SUPER = 2, F_SALARY = 80000*/ 
UPDATE FACULTY
SET F_SUPER = 2
WHERE F_ID = 5;
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to us if you explained the business rules instead of letting us try to reverse engineeer them from your code.

Answer (score 1):

> I wrote this ROW Level trigger(was below) already, but don't know how
>   to get a statement level trigger which can do the same thing like
>   this. And because cannot use :NEW / :OLD in statement level, then
>   confused...

Statement level trigger and row level triggers are not the same. They are provided by Oracle depending on the usage. Hence all row level triggers cannot be replaced with a statement level triggers. See below definition and usage:

Row-level triggers for data-related activities

> • Row-level triggers execute once for each row in a transaction.
>
> • Row-level triggers are the most common type of triggers; they are
>   often used in data auditing applications.
>
> • Row-level trigger is identified by the FOR EACH ROW clause in the
>   CREATE TRIGGER command.

Statement-level triggers for transaction-related activities

> • Statement-level triggers execute once for each transaction. For
>   example, if a single transaction inserted 500 rows into the  Customer
>   table, then a statement-level trigger on that table would only be
>   executed once.
>
> • Statement-level triggers therefore are not often used for
>   data-related activities; they are normally used to enforce additional 
>   security measures on the types of transactions that may be performed
>   on a table.
>
> • Statement-level triggers are the default type of triggers created
>   and are identified by omitting the FOR EACH ROW clause  in the CREATE
>   TRIGGER command.

Example of Statement Level Trigger:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER Before_Update_Stat_product 
BEFORE UPDATE ON product 
Begin 
  INSERT INTO table  
  Values('Before update, statement level',sysdate); 
END; 
/
```

Answer (score 0):

He wants to update the whole table (with filter) with a statement level trigger and IMO the trigger should be with "after insert or update for".

Comment: This should have been a comment  and not an answer. Moreover, you don't guess that it's "He"